# What is Sasuke's base class?

Tags: npc, d20-modern

I'm trying out the [Naruto d20](http://www.narutod20.com/) rpg right now and I intend to have my players interact with Team 7 in a sort of training scuffle. It wouldn't really be a fight, as they would be chunnin while Team 7 would be genin.

I don't have much experience with the modern d20, which might be my problem, but I can see from the description of the base classes:

- Naruto maps out perfectly to the Tough Hero class
- Sakura maps out perfectly to the Dedicated Hero class

But I can't figure out what would be the base class for Sasuke. I'm thinking Smart Hero, but he seems to be more of an all-rounder. His fangirls would suggest some charisma and he seems to have decent at least physical stats.

I've checked the given builds but I don't see him anywhere, so I'm curious: if someone built him as a NPC which of the base classes he would start out in or have the most levels in?

Comment: If you're looking for subjective opinions about which traits the character should have Anime & Manga SE may be better place to ask this than here. http://anime.stackexchange.com/

Comment: @JoshuaAslanSmith what you're saying is true but I think RPG knowledge is rar-er than manga knowledge thus it would be easier to find a d20 buff who happens to know the manga rather than a manga buff who knows the Modern d20 system.

Comment: I agree, but I also think you may wait awhile to get an answer here, or end up answering it yourself. If you framed the question on Anime & Manga SE correctly they could answer it (As in you breakdown the core values of the different classes and then ask them which values they think more closely align with Sasuke).

Comment: The "seems to be more of..." would go better on the Anime/Manga SE but the latter question "has someone made this NPC" is definitely on-topic. I second @JoshuaAslanSmith's warning that it might take a while for someone with experience to answer, though.

Comment: @LitheOhm I'll leave this a bit longer and if nobody has any opinions, I'll just build him as a Smart Hero and close this question. The problem is that Sasuke's weaknesses are not things which can be mapped out to stats so if I go from a pure lore perspective I'd wind up either overpowered or overstretched and useless.

Comment: I know nothing about the system, but as I see it, naruto is tough, sakura is dedicated, but sasuke is talented. That is why is more of an antihero most of the series, since, all throughout the series, he didn't have to put too much effort in to succeed.

Comment: @kravaros I think yours is as good of a answer as I'm going to get as I made the question very specific. Could you please convert it into a answer so I can make it chose it, I'm going to go with talented = Smart Hero. It also goes well with Kakashi himself being a Smart Hero.

Comment: ***"Naruto maps out perfectly to the Tough Hero class"*** -- Total aside, but adult Naruto's highest stat is almost definitely Charisma i.e. force of personality.

Comment: @starwed Oh yes Naruto's most current build would include Tough Hero and Charismatic Hero in equal proportion topped off with the Senjutsu using class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The consensus in the comments and from what I can gather from other places is that the first levels should be in Smart Hero.

If somebody else wants to post another opinion as a answer I'll select it as the chosen answer.